# Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown

Tags: rest, sharepoint-online, powerapps-canvas

I am creating custom connector in PowerApps to connect to SharePoint Online (not allowed to use default connectors).

I created an registered an app in Azure AD, gave it "Have full control of all site collections" permissions to SharePoint Online,
Screenshot 1.
Azure AD configuration Screenshot 2,3:
PowerApp Custom connector Screenshot 4 :
PowerApp Error Screenshot 5 :

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sayBa.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guuev.png)

[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1GRA.png)

[Screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMRTG.png)

[Screenshot 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPtEj.png)

Resource url in Security Tab of connector:
[Resource url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M7xJ.png)

Any Suggestions ? Thank-you.